# How to export to Excel numbers as text fields from Mathematica?

Tags: xml, excel, wolfram-mathematica

I have a list containing telephone numbers in the form "+74951234567" and I wish to export it to Excel without quotes preserving original appearance with the plus sign. In Excel I can set the cell format to "Text" and then entering +74951234567 without quotes will not result in converting it to number. Is it possible to force `Export` in *Mathematica* to create Text cells?

### UPDATE

I have found an approach which allows to get what I wish: I need to export the table as XML data with formatting information added. For example, the `"ss:StyleID" -> "s21"` statement in `XMLElement["Cell", {"ss:StyleID" -> "s21"}, {XMLElement["Data", {"ss:Type" -> "String"}, {"+74951234567"}]}]` formats the cell as "Text".

I have found this by saving the table as "XML Table" from Excel and then `Import`ing the generated file in *Mathematica*:

```
XMLData = Import["test.xml", "IncludeNamespaces" -> "Unparsed"]
```

The `XMLData` can further be modified inside *Mathematica* and `Export`ed backward to XML:

```
Export["test-from MMa.xml", XMLData]
```

The exported file is opened by Excel as ordinary worksheet and can be manipulated in the usual manner.

But I still need help because I am not familiar with XML and *Mathematica*'s XML capabilities.

### UPDATE 2

It seems that another option would be using [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) Java library which I have not tried yet.

Comment: Alexey, why are you posting this here rather than Mathematica.SE?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The problem is Excel-related. I thought that there may also be indirect solutions using some Excel capabilities.

Comment: I see.  Good call I suppose as I don't use Excel and I cannot be of help.

Answer (score 4):

Looks fairly simple. Use quotes in Mathematica to make Excel interpret data as text.

[image]

Comment: +1. But is it possible to specify the "Text" format for the cells so that I can be sure that accidental editing will not break the cell contents?

Comment: You can send the data as a string through NETLink, and it will automatically format as a text cell, and I'm sure you could directly operate on the cell format too.  Here is a link to a relevant thread: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Oct/msg00390.html

Comment: I looks an overkill to use `NETLink` for such a simple task. I hoped that there are some (undocumented?) `FormattedData` options which allow to do such things.

Comment: Using Export with quotes seems to be reliable for generating text cells.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible at this time, but here's how I'd go about trying it.  Try creating a simple spreadsheet with what you want and `Import` the `FormattedData` element to see what the form of the data should be.  Then try exporting the data back using that form.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not produce cells formatted as "Text". All the cells in the notebook has the same `Style` directives irrespectively to the format ("Text" etc.) specifyed in Excel.

Comment: Okay, I didn't think it was supported.  Make them strings and handle them that way.  It's not perfect, but better than treating them as numbers.