# Generating Excel-compatible XML files from Mathematica

Tags: xml, excel, wolfram-mathematica

Excel can save its Workbooks in the "XML Table" format preserving all the formatting and styling information and then open and edit them as native Excel workbooks. I wish to generate such files by *Mathematica* for Excel programmatically adding formatting information for rows, columns, cells etc.

The first stumbling problem is that even when I `Import` Excel-generated file in *Mathematica* and then just `Export` it backward to `"XML"` the resulting file cannot be opened by Excel. Opening it in a text editor shows that this file contains apostrophes instead of quotes. Adding the `"AttributeQuoting" -> "\""` option to `Export` fixes this but the resulting file still cannot be opened by Excel. More careful comparison shows that `Export` also drops the most of namespace prefixes in the generated file.

How to generate Excel-compatible XML files from *Mathematica*?

P.S. This question comes from the previous question: "[How to export to Excel numbers as text fields from Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11256618/590388)"

Comment: Version 8 can save as .xlsx which *is* the XML based format: does this do what you need? By the way you will probably get faster answers on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ - most of the experts have moved there.

Comment: @Verbeia When I simply `Export` XML data to .xlsx format I get a file where all the XML data are simply put in one cell. So it is not what I need. Thanks for suggestion, now I have created [separate question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7853/280) on mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. [From the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/XML/tutorial/ImportingXML.html#18255),

> Some documents use names in a non-namespace-compliant fashion, because
>   the XML namespace recommendation, which extends XML, was made after
>   the initial XML recommendation. `"IncludeNamespaces"->"Unparsed"` is
>   provided to allow parsing of these documents. The name is always
>   represented as the exact single string that appears in the XML file.
>   Unless absolutely necessary, this option value should not be used.

With the option `"IncludeNamespaces"->"Unparsed"` everything is nice and even the `"AttributeQuoting" -> "\""` option is not needed:

```
XMLData = Import["test.xml", "IncludeNamespaces" -> "Unparsed"];
Export["test-from MMa.xml", XMLData]
```

The exported file is opened by Excel without warnings.